# Exact equation - two domains of solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this problem:

$y^2-1 = (f(y)-2xy)y'$

$y(1)=4$

when

$f(t) = t$ for $t\leq2$ ,

and $2$ for $t\gt2$.

**So in the domain of $y\gt2$ we get:**

$y^2-1=(2-2xy)y'$

after soving the exact equation I've got this solution:

**$xy^2-x-2y=c$**

and with the boundary condition [$y(1)=4$] got:

**$xy^2-x-2y-7=0$**

as the particular solution in the domian.

**In a similar way I've got this solution in the domian of $y\leq2$:**

$xy^2-x-\frac{1}{2}y^2-c=0$

The main question is: **how do I apply the boundary condition on this part of the solution?**

**It is undefined for $y=4$ since the domain is $y\leq2$.**

Now it might be entirely wrong, but I thought about demanding continuity at $y=2$ and concluded that $c$ should be 9,
by applying $\lim_{y\to 2^+}$ and $\lim_{y\to 2^-}$.

but it seems like I've turned the solution into a function which is $x(y)$, and also calculated the limit by treating x as a constant.

**I wonder what is the meaning of the two different domains for the solutions?**

**and also, how do I unite them into one solution? should it even be done?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your calculus which is correct
$\quad y(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{x^2+7x+1}}{x}$ .

The study of this function shows that $\quad 0<x<\frac{11}{3}$ for $y>2$ .
$$\boxed{y(x)=\frac{1+\sqrt{x^2+7x+1}}{x}\quad\text{in}\quad 0<x<\frac{11}{3}}$$

For $y\leq 2$ your calculus is also correct, which leads to :
$$y=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2x-1+c}{2x-1}}$$
In order to insure the continuity at $(\frac{11}{3}\:,\:2)$ solving $\quad 2=\sqrt{\frac{2\frac{11}{3}-1+c}{2\frac{11}{3}-1}}$ for $c$ gives $c=19$.
$$\boxed{y=\sqrt{\frac{2x+18}{2x-1}}\quad\text{in}\quad x\geq \frac{11}{3}}$$